# Edimax EW-7811Un wifi adapter not working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, adapter

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-Bit and have a Edimax EW-7811Un wifi adapter. I have tired to get it to work but have no luck.

when I run lsusb command I get:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
```

iwconfig shows that nothing is being read or connected:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I have tired numerous forums and tutorials but cant get it to work, dont know what I am doing wrong.

Can someone give a clear step by step method to get this to work?

uname -r: (Kernel Version)

```
3.16.0-34-generic
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been reported to work:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10
sudo depmod -a
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

Reboot

([Source](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes#installation))

Comment: PERFECT!!! Thank you mate, been searching long and hard for this.

Comment: Should I be worried about all the failed attempts and random drivers I have tried to download and install? Is there a way to clean/flush them?

Comment: This likely replaced all that since it worked

Comment: Under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the adaptor seems to be supported but the connection is intermittent.  For anyone facing this problem while applying this patch, I recommend just disconnecting and re-connecting to the Wifi hotspot.

Comment: how do we undo this - i did this and found that it did not support 5GHz. My internal realtek8723be works just fine too (i manually built and installed rtlwifi_new). So i want to go back to that. Presently after this, when i take out the edimax usb, i dont even get the enable-wifi listed. So how to undo this ?

Comment: @ustulation `sudo dkms remove 8192cu/1.10`, `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu makes newer kernels (and X Windows) available to the LTS releases, called the [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack). I installed the latest kernel on my 14.04 (Trusty) system, which at the time of writing is the kernel for Xenial (16.04). Newer kernels have newer drivers and firmware.

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Then reboot to upgrade to the Xenial kernel. On my system, the Edimax adapter worked fine afterward.